# jQuery styling tricks -Check for a class name

Tags: jquery-1.9

I would like to check whether the particular `sytle / class` has already been applied on given element.

What is the correct jQuery function to check this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .hasClass()

The Syntax is

```
$(selector).hasClass(classname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use hasClass();

```
$('#mydiv').hasClass('testClass');
```

ie...

```
  if($('#mydiv').hasClass('testClass')){  //YOUR CODE HERE if TRUE }
```